# TCPの接続終了フェーズの流れをWireSharkで確認したいです。

Tags: tcp

## 背景

[パケットキャプチャの教科書](https://www.sbcr.jp/product/4797390711/) を読んで、TCPについて勉強しています。

TCPの接続終了フェーズは、以下のように4ウェイハンドシェイクであることを理解しました。

```
      TCP A                                                TCP B

  1.  ESTABLISHED                                          ESTABLISHED

  2.  (Close)
      FIN-WAIT-1  --> <SEQ=100><ACK=300><CTL=FIN,ACK>  --> CLOSE-WAIT

  3.  FIN-WAIT-2  <-- <SEQ=300><ACK=101><CTL=ACK>      <-- CLOSE-WAIT

  4.                                                       (Close)
      TIME-WAIT   <-- <SEQ=300><ACK=101><CTL=FIN,ACK>  <-- LAST-ACK

  5.  TIME-WAIT   --> <SEQ=101><ACK=301><CTL=ACK>      --> CLOSED

  6.  (2 MSL)
      CLOSED

                         Normal Close Sequence

                               Figure 13.
```

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc793#section-3.5 引用

## 質問

上記のTCP接続を終了する通信を、実際にWireSharkでキャプチャして確認したいです。
どのようなタイミングでキャプチャするのがよいのでしょうか？
TCPの接続が、いつ終了されるか理解していません。
たとえばHTTPは、いつTCPの接続が終了されるのでしょうか？

## 回答をもらった上での補足

curlやtelnetでHTTP接続してからしばらく待てば、以下の様なTCPの終了フェーズを確認することができました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 現状の書き方だと「接続終了フェーズ」の流れが分からないのか、それとも「WireShark の操作方法」が分からないのかが曖昧な気がします。

Comment: 「接続終了フェーズの流れ」と「WireSharkの操作方法」は理解しています。「接続終了フェーズ」のタイミングが分からず、いつキャプチャすればよいのかが分かりませんでした。（質問に追記しました）。

Comment: ずっとキャプチャーしておいて必要なパケットが流れるまで待てばよいのでは？
HTTPについては回答にも記したとおり, 要求が途切れしばらくしたあとです

Comment: ありがとうございます。おしゃっる通り、しばらく待てば終了フェーズの流れを確認することができました（質問に追記）。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP connection調べる目的に, HTTPは(そのままでは)向いていない気がします

3ウェイ・ハンドシェイク, FIN-WAIT/CLOSE-WAIT など, TCP connectionを閉じて再度開くにはコストがかかるので, HTTPでは一つの connectionで複数のやり取り行うのが普通
(プロトコルとして古いけど) FTPとか telnet使うのがよいかも

いつ HTTP connectionが切れるか ⇨ 要求が途切れしばらくしたあと

---

あるいは, telnet利用して古い接続(HTTP/1.0) 行う手もあります
参考 https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Evolution_of_HTTP

```
$ telnet www.example.com 80

> Connected to www.example.com.
> Escape character is '^]'.

GET /
```

(最初の行がコマンドライン, その次が相手からのメッセージ)
(最後の行が, HTTPメソッド手入力)

Answer (score 2):

パケットキャプチャ、楽しいですよね。
(楽しくない状況で使うことも多いですが)
私も回答としてまっさきに思いついたのが@oririさんの書かれているFTPでした。

HTTPですと、質問で書かれている書籍のダウンロードファイル、
CHAPTER6の「http_request_get.pcapng」とかが該当しそうです。
クライアントからのGETに対してHTTP200で応答した後、
クライアントからFINを送って(No.14)サーバもFINを返して(No.16)終了しています。

実サイトでHTTP通信をキャプチャしてもHTTPSがほとんどで読みきれないと思いますので
ローカルで簡易サーバを立てて確認するのがいいと思います。

Comment: 初期のダウンロードふぃある「https://www.sbcr.jp/support/14182/ 」で、実際にTCPの接続終了フェーズを確認することができました！

Answer (score -2):

HTTPについては下記のサイトを参照してみてください。

[第1回　HTTPプロトコルとは：超入門HTTPプロトコル - ＠IT](https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/articles/1703/29/news045.html)

> たとえばHTTPでは、いつTCPの接続が終了されるのでしょうか？

このような通信について見ることができるのがWireSharkです。
WireSharkを起動し、ブラウザーでサイトを開くと、その通信状態がわかります。
まずはWireSharkをインストールし、起動してみてください。